# Simplify Product $\prod_{k=2}^{n} \left(1 - \frac{2}{k (k+1)}\right)$

Tags: infinite-product

I try to simplify an expression ([wolfram link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product_%28k%3D2%29%5En%281-2%2F%28k%20%28k%2B1%29%29%29)) but i really do not know enough about the topic.

$\prod_{k=2}^{n} \left(1 - \frac{2}{k (k+1)}\right)$

I can see the result but i do not know how to get there. I promised a friend to help with homework but now we are both stuck. Can someone show us how to think about a problem like that.

The result is supposed to be $\frac{(n+2)}{(3 n)}$ so i assume that i can split the product in two products, remove some elements from either product and somehow elimitate the remaining products with each other. I failed miserably when i tried it though.

Comment: Write the factors as $\frac{k^2+k-2}{k(k+1)}$, and look closely at the numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1-\frac2{k(k+1)}=\frac{k^2+k-2}{k(k+1)}=\frac{(k-1)(k+2)}{k(k+1)}=\frac{\frac{k-1}{k+1}}{\frac k{k+2}}=\frac{v_k}{v_{k+1}}$$
where
$$v_k=\frac{k-1}{k+1}$$
so the desired product gives by telescoping
$$\frac{v_2}{v_{n+1}}=\frac{n+2}{3n}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$
1 - \frac 2{k(k+1)}
=\frac {k^2 + k - 2}{k(k+1)}
=\frac {(k-1)(k+2)}{k(k+1)}
$$

Then when you make the product of these, most terms telescope.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the first calculus, you should replace -k by k .

Comment: @mvggz thanks.${{}}$